# Recycle IIS7 Application Pool with C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, application-pool

I have read through all of the threads on here on how to do this programmatically but I can not get it to work.  A little background on how my code works.

You log in to the site and choose App Pool monitor.  There is a drop down that allows you to choose the server you are looking for.  I have a stored procedure that will pull the app pools from that server and display them in a grid.  I then have this code that I am testing:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     string appPool = rdr["AppPoolName"].ToString();
     string permission = rdr["Permission"].ToString();
     string serverIP = rdr["ServerIP"].ToString();

     if (permission == "E")
     {
          lblErrorStart.Visible = false;

          using (var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverIP))
          {
               ApplicationPool poolName = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appPool];
               poolName.Stop();
               lblSuccess.Visible = true;
          }
     }

     else
     {
          lblErrorStart.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

The reader I have created pools the AppPoolName, ServerIP, and Permission from SQL.

I use a DirectoryEntry for IIS6 and it works great but it will not work for IIS7.

```
using (DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://" + serverIP + "/W3SVC/AppPools/" + appPool)))
{
     w3svc.Invoke("Recycle", null);
     lblSuccess.Visible = true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The exception I get with the Directory Services is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know it's not working? How would you **really** know if the app pool has been recycled or not? We had this issue several months ago and tried to figure out a way to see if it's really recycling or not. We turned on tracing in IIS but it didn't log any messages, which we thought meant it wasn't working. What we did then, was create a dummy service and a console app that would ping that service every 0.5 a second. Then, we recycled the AppPool that was hosting the service, and oddly enough, we saw a delay in the ping response, which meant it actually did recycle.

Try changing `w3svc.Invoke("Recycle", null);` to `w3svc.Invoke("Stop", null);`. If that stops the AppPool, then you can be almost sure that `Recycle` will work just fine. Note that invoking a `Recycle` operation **does not block**, so if your code depends on the AppPool to be up and running after a recycle, you need to check for its state before continuing.

### Edit:

Give this a shot:

In the `Windows Features` window, make sure `IIS 6 Management Compatibility`  is enabled.

[image]

Open up the Start menu and type in "services", then press Enter. Make sure `IIS Admin Service` is running. Now try to invoke the command and see if it works.

Comment: If you recycle, the PID will change because the w3wp process is terminated and a new one is created.  My PID never changes.

Comment: Well then something else is going on. You're not getting an exception, are you? I'm also assuming you've tried running the application as an administrator?

Comment: @Matt Updated my answer, give it another shot.

Comment: I checked the server that I am trying to access and all of the IIS6 management compatibility options are installed except for the console.  The IIS service is running as well.  I am not getting an exception either.  However, I am having issues stepping through the code.  It requires going through a login page which is screwing the debug up.  I might just create a console app and try the same code and step through it that way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35921/discussion-between-matt-and-poweredbyorange)

Comment: Dont know why but it started working.  I still get the COMException but it works.

Comment: That's strange... if `IIS 6 WMI Compatibility` is turned on you shouldn't get the exception.